# inexplicable behavior mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a question about my problem with redirection.
I tried do htaccess rules, but unfortunately, it doesn't working on my server.
What I wanted:
Old URL `http://www.elektrolety.com/g-1maj-2010/ipage00022.htm` (number from 1 to 115)
New URL `http://www.elektrolety.com/g-1maj-2010/img00022.html` (direct translation by htaccess)

My .htaccess file included next rows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /g-1maj-2010/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.htm$ $1/img$3.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

It work good on htaccess.madewithlove.be tester, but on my server not. The OptionSymlinks is prohibited by provider.

Can you help me with this problem? Thank You!

Comment: Mod rewrite won't work without `Options FollowSymlinks`

Comment: OK, when mod rewrite won't work without Options FollowSymlinks, is another way how to transform htaccess rules, can be redirection working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OK, when mod rewrite won't work without Options FollowSymlinks, is another way how to transform htaccess rules, can be redirection working?

You can use mod_alias instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^([^.]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.htm$ /g-1maj-2010/$1/img$3.html
```

Comment: O.M.G, i'm really tired :-)
Thank you, it's working!
I was little modified to: RedirectMatch 301 ^([^.]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)\.htm$ /$1/img$3.html
Again thanx!